# Is split() of a static string a run-time or compile-time operation?

Tags: python

Coming from a Perl background, I'm used to something like:

```
my @words = qw(fee fi fo fum);
```

I'm wondering if the following Python incurs a run-time performance hit:

```
words = 'fee fi fo fum'.split()
```

or if `words` is bound at compile-time.

Comment: `split` returns a new list every time, so you couldn't actually store a single value to use for `words`. I suppose you could precompute a value and copy it every time the statement runs, if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even in PERL it can be bound at compile time because every time you get through that statement a new fresh list must be created.

In other words in Python when you see

```
x = ['fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum']
```

the code cannot just load a specific object address into `x` because it must be a new fresh list object each time you get on the statement. Consider

```
def foo():
    return ['fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum']

x = foo()
x[0] = 'bar'

print foo()[0]   # must be 'fee'
print x[0]       # must be 'bar'
```

Python however does some optimization for immutables; for example:

```
def foo():
    return (1, 2, 3)
```

actually always return the very same object (it doesn't allocate a new tuple each time), and for

```
def foo():
    return 3 * 4
```

it actually returns 12 without making the multiplication at runtime.

Your example however cannot be resolved to loading a constant computed at compile time, it must be at least a list "literal" (that is indeed a list generator creating a new object each time is evaluated).

IIRC constant folding is only done at compile time for binary operators on number/strings and not for any function call (note that in Python it's legal, even if bad practice, to change for example the standard function `len`, so you cannot be sure that `len("foo")` always returns 3).

Calls of methods on standard strings passing only constants could indeed IMO be moved at compile time, but AFAIK it's not done at this moment (and it's not common, so may be the gain is not worth the effort).

Comment: Just for clarity, Python *may* choose to optimize by only using one immutable object if it feels like it, but there are no promises on that score.  (FWIW a quick test made it look like Jython may not.)

Comment: There were even bugs in CPython that weren't fixed until 3.3 with regards to resolving certain constant expressions at compile-time. Things like `(2+3)*4` weren't being fully evaluated.

Comment: I had it reversed, things like `4*(2+3)` won't be fully evaluated as they should.

Comment: @arshajii: The problem was not because of bugs but because of the approach to the problem: constant folding was done in the peephole optimizer where it's difficult to solve all cases. Now it's instead done (also) at the AST level before code generation.

Answer (score 5):

You can view bytecode using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>>
>>> def f():
...     words = 'fee fi fo fum'.split()
... 
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('fee fi fo fum')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (words)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

`split` (as loaded by `LOAD_ATTR`) is called via `CALL_FUNCTION` and its result is assigned to `words` via `STORE_FAST` at runtime. In other words, `x.split()` is not resolved at compile-time, even if `x` is a hardcoded string.

Of course, the performance difference between using `'fee fi fo fum'.split()` and its result, namely `['fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum']`, is going to be negligible, so *don't* change from one to the other only for the sake of a performance boost.

Comment: I'm super new to the bytecode.. what is it that indicates to you the run time/compile time difference in the bytecode output?

Comment: @EMS You can see that `split` is called because of the `CALL_FUNCTION` operand (which calls `split` as loaded by `LOAD_ATTR`). I elaborated in the answer a little.

Comment: If it was handled at compile time, you would just see a `LOAD_CONST` that loaded a list or tuple, then a `STORE_FAST` to store it in the variable.